# Getting the height of a element hidden by a container with height 0

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm encountering an issue with scrollHeight and offsetHeight that I suspect is a product of abusing the css rendering engine.

I'm attempting to get an accurate scrollHeight or offsetHeight for an element in the following context.

**CSS**

```
.transitionHeight {
overflow: hidden;
transition: height 1s;
}

.closed {
  height: 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 !important; 
  border: none !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
  margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;  
  width: .1rem; 
}
```

**HTML (snippet)**

```
<div class="fullHeight closed" id="addressTarget" style="height: 1119px;">
  <div class="widget bar contact" id="addressDetails">
    <div class="column left">
      Header:
    </div>
    <p class="column right">Information</p>
    <div class="column left">
      Header 2:
    </div>
    <a href="" class="column right">
      More Details
    </a>
    <div class="column left">
      Like us on Facebook at:
    </div>
    <a href="" target="_blank" class="column right">
      Even More Details
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Calls to `document.querySelector("#addressDetails").clientHeight` and `document.querySelector("#addressDetails").offsetHeight`  are both returning a seemingly random integer when the closed style is applied to the #addressTarget,  when #addressTarget does not have the closed style attached either call returns an accurate value.  Ideally the code should be able to calculate the correct height while the style is applied to avoid an FOUC, is there a way to get this value?

The goal here is to set document.querySelector("#addressTarget").style.height to the value returned by the height check to create a reliable slide down.  If the javascript call cannot return the required height is there a css rule that can be applied to .heightTransition that will a) represent a transition target and b) be calculated correctly?

(While the exact definitions of .column .left and .right are not required to solve this problem I'm including them here in case they are useful, however the best place I can pull them from is the original .scss so I'm providing them in sass rather than css:

```
$rook: 500px;
$bishop: 750px;

.column {
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 1rem;
 box-sizing: border-box;

 &.left {
   width: 100%;
   vertical-align: top;
   text-align: center;

   @include applyWiderThan($rook) {
     width: 33%; 
     text-align: right; }
   @include applyWiderThan($bishop) {
     width: 20%} }
 &.right {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: scroll;
   border: 1px solid mix($gold, white, 20%);
   border-radius: 10px/10px;

   @include applyWiderThan($rook) {
     width: 65%;
     border: none;
     border-radius: none; }
  @include applyWiderThan($bishop) {
    font-size: 1.5rem; 
    width: 78%}     }
 }
```

Comment: Are you restricted by any framework? I'm quite sure there's some re-design needed for your particular problem.

Comment: hi @skmasq, there are no restrictions for this; other than the logic flow matching:  1) show the page with links to sections which are links to new pages prior to JavaScript modification (to support non-js scenarios), 2) post JS the links should add a class to an element that triggers the transition.  I have looked at modifying the actual widget with the JS call but the animations tend to uglier than I would like.  The transition should be height only, which is why I've moved to a wrapper, but I'm open to other design patterns.

Comment: First of all I would suggest to use different styles depending if client has or hasn't got JS enabled via `<noscript>` tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_noscript.asp

Comment: I'm all for noscript, but in this case it's redundant markup.  When the scripts are off the HREF of the anchor element (not included in this question) is the destination page (i.e. native load state).  This also supports any case when the script might break.  When the script runs it sets the HREF of the anchor to "#" so that all the relevant behaviours can happen in page.

I'm moving over to a transform based solution and I think it meets my needs better.